# Tail calls in architectures without a call stack

Tags: functional-programming, callstack, tail-call-optimization

My answer for a recent [question about GOTOs and tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483405/is-erlangs-recursive-functions-not-just-a-goto/1483582) was phrased in terms of a call stack. I'm worried that it wasn't sufficiently general, so I ask you: how is the notion of a tail call (or equivalent) useful in architectures without a call stack?

In continuation passing, all called functions replace the calling function, and are thus tail calls, so "tail call" doesn't seem to be a useful distinction. In messaging and event based architectures, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent, though please correct me if I'm wrong. The latter two architectures are interesting cases as they are associated with OOP, rather than FP. What about other architectures? Were the old Lisp machines based on call-stacks?

Edit: According to "[What the heck is: Continuation Passing Style (CPS)](http://www.sidhe.org/~dan/blog/archives/000185.html)" (and Alex below), the equivalent of a tail call under continuation passing is not "called function replaces calling function" but "calling function passes the continuation it was given, rather than creating a new continuation". This type of tail call is useful, unlike what I asserted.

Also, I'm not interested in systems that use call stacks at a lower level, for the higher level doesn't require a call stack. This restriction doesn't apply to Alex's answer because he's writing about the fact that other invocation architectures ([is this the right term?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485156/categorizing-architectures-based-on-calling-features)) often have a call stack equivalent, not that they have a call stack somewhere under the hood. In the case of continuation passing, the structure is like an [arborescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)), but with edges in the opposite direction. Call stack equivalents are highly relevant to my interests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the off chance that this question interests someone other than me, I have an [expanded answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483405/is-erlangs-recursive-functions-not-just-a-goto/1496088#1496088) for the other question that also answers this one. Here's the nutshell, non-rigorous version.

When a computational system performs sub-computations (i.e. a computation starts and must pause while another computation is performed because the first depends on the result of the second), a dependency relation between execution points naturally arises. In call-stack based architectures, the relation is topologically a [path graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathGraph.html). In CPS, it's a tree, where every path between the root and a node is a continuation. In message passing and threading, it's a collection of path graphs. Synchronous event handling is basically message passing. Starting a sub-calculation involves extending the dependency relation, except in a tail call which replaces a leaf rather than appending to it.

Translating tail calling to asynchronous event handling is more complex, so instead consider a more general version. If A is subscribed to an event on channel 1, B is subscribed to the same event on channel 2 and B's handler merely fires the event on channel 1 (it translates the event across channels), then A can be subscribed to the event on channel 2 instead of subscribing B. This is more general because the equivalent of a tail call requires that

- A's subscription on channel 1 be canceled when A is subscribed on channel 2
- the handlers are self-unsubscribing (when invoked, they cancel the subscription)

Now for two systems that don't perform sub-computations: lambda calculus (or term rewriting systems in general) and RPN. For lambda calculus, tail calls roughly correspond to a sequence of reductions where the term length is O(1) (see iterative processes in [SICP section 1.2](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2)). Take RPN to use a data stack and an operations stack (as opposed to a stream of operations; the operations are those yet to be processed), and an environment that maps symbols to a sequence of operations. Tail calls could correspond to processes with O(1) stack growth.

Answer (score 4):

"Architectures without a call stack" typically "simulate" one at some level -- for example, back in the time of IBM 360, we used the [S-Type Linkage Convention](http://everything2.com/title/System%252F370+S-type+linkage+convention) using register-save areas and arguments-lists indicated, by convention, by certain general-purpose registers.

So "tail call" can still matter: does the calling function need to preserve the information necessary to resume execution after the calling point (once the called function is finished), or does it know there IS going to be no execution after the calling point, and so simply reuse *its caller's* "info to resume execution" instead?

So for example a tail call optimization might mean not appending the continuation needed to resume execution on whatever linked list is being used for the purpose... which I like to see as a "call stack simulation" (at some level, though it IS obviously a more flexible arrangement -- don't want to have continuation-passing fans jumping all over my answer;-).

Comment: Yeah, I realized I was wrong about tail calls in CPS after reading http://www.sidhe.org/~dan/blog/archives/000185.html

Comment: BTW: a nice, real-life, and relevant example of a call-stack-less architecture is the Parrot Virtual Machine whose control-flow is entirely based on continuations. (Interestingly, it is also register-based, i.e. not only doesn't it have a call stack, it also doesn't have a data stack either.)

Comment: Yeah, last Thursday Alison Randall spoke about Parrot (and Pynie, her Python 3 compiler for it) at Baypiggies, the SF Bay Area Python Interest Group. I specifically asked her about tail call optimization and she reassured me it IS there (with a tiny twist: some info gets accumulated to still allow informative "non-stack traces" in case of exception, which a straightforward tail call optimization would not give).