# Categorizing architectures based on calling features

Tags: architecture, function-calls

There are different ways of calling functions: call stacks, continuation passing, messaging and event handling. What do you call the category of these features? Invocation? What do you call architectures categorized by these features? Invocation architecture?

Sub question: Other than the four given, what are some examples of this type of feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for sort of generalizes the idea of **calling conventions**, so you might be able to get away with using that in an expanded sense.

"Function calling style" and "calling style" may also work.

Comment: It is tempting, but "calling convention" is so useful as it is. I wouldn't want its meaning to be context sensitive. If I could generalize a term without the new meaning hiding the old, I would.

Answer (score 0):

"Ways of calling functions" seems appropriate to me. Why go out of your way to make things more difficult than they already are?

If you're writing a paper that is using this phrase **very frequently**, you might save a few words by defining what you mean by "Invocation Architecture" at the top. I'm not aware of any term used for this.

Comment: The question came about because I was trying to determine what tail calls look like in non-callstack based architectures. I was hoping to find a term more specific than "ways of calling functions" to help in the search. The sub-question was the immediate inspiration for the main question.

Comment: I'm also interested in mapping out "invocation space" for no specific goal.

Comment: "Function calling style"? That would make it clear that CPS is an element of that collection.

Comment: @Novelocrat: Perhaps. Not all architectures have what are called "functions" (though they have something equivalent). Maybe just "calling style"? Goes well with "calling convention". Put that in an answer, it might be the winner.